# Having trouble using while loop in java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a while loop that asks user input. If user types "hi" it will print "hello" and if user types "done" it will end the loop , but if user types anything else or integer it will say "type either hi or done.". The code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(!(input.nextLine()).equals("done")){

        if((input.nextLine()).equals("hi"))
        {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Type hi or done");
        }
    }      
}
```

But with this code it is asking user input two times before it showing the result. What is the problem and how to deal with it in the most effective way?

Comment: You are asking for input (up to a new line) twice.

Comment: store input.nextLine() into a string and the use in if case

Answer (score 6):

You should only call `input.nextLine()` once per loop.  Write your code like this:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String line;
        while (!(line = input.nextLine()).equals("done")) {

            if (line.equals("hi")) {
                System.out.println("Hello");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Type hi or done");
            }
        }
    }


}
```

The way you wrote it above, you were throwing away the `while`'s `line` by calling `nextLine()` in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should save the input as a variable, I've called it `nextLine`.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String nextLine = "";

while(!(nextLine.equals("done")){

    nextLine = input.nextLine();
    if((nextLine).equals("hi")){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Type hi or done");
    }
}
```

Comment: You calling `nextLine()` twice before any output is generated. You need to move `nextLine = input.nextLine();` to the bottom of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following do...while() loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
        String inputLine = input.nextLine();

        if(inputLine.equals("hi"))
        {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
        else if(!inputLine.equals("done"))
        {
            System.out.println("Type hi or done");
        }
    }while(!inputLine.equals("done")); 
}
```